# Editing Highcharts.js donut data programmatically va JS

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to do the same for donut (editing the donut data programmatically), but the code just wouldn't work for me, although  the syntax seems to be straghtforward here.

My goal is to find the data point in the donut which corresponds to the given x-axis value and set the value to 10. Any ideas on this ?

Here's the [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/caLv5d6x/)

```
btnEdit.click(function() {
    // chart.series[0].data[0].update(x += 10); - this code doesn't work
    var x = prompt("Please enter your name");
    // find the data point that corresponds to x
    // Set it to 10
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you are looking for a point by its name, not its x value, because x value is a number, name is a string (for categorized data there is natural mapping between those two).

```
btnEdit.click(function() {
// chart.series[0].data[0].update(x += 10); - this code doesn't work
var i = 0,
    points = chart.series[0].data,
    len = points.length,
    x = prompt("Please enter your name"),
    point;

for (; i < len; i++) {
    point = points[i];
    if (point.name === x) {
      point.update({
        y: 10
      });
      break;
    }
}

// find the data point that corresponds to x
// Set it to 10
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/caLv5d6x/3/

The above solution assumes that you have points which their name are unique - but it doesn't have to be like that.
A small adjustment is enough:

```
 btnEdit.click(function() {
// chart.series[0].data[0].update(x += 10); - this code doesn't work
  var x = prompt("Please enter your name");

chart.series[0].data.forEach(function (point) {
    if (point.name === x) {
    point.update({
        y: 10
    }, false, false);
  }
});

chart.redraw();
// find the data point that corresponds to x
// Set it to 10
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/caLv5d6x/4/